# Formatting Date Strings in R

Tags: r, date

I have two columns of differently formatted date strings that I need to make the same format,

the first is in the form:

```
vt_dev_date = "6/20/2016 7:45"
```

the second is in the form

```
vt_other = "2016-06-14 20:21:29.0"
```

If could get them both in the same form down to the minute that would be great. I have tried

```
strptime(vt_dev_date,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
strptime(vt_other,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

and for the second one, it works and I get
"2016-06-14 20:21:00 EDT"

But for the first string, it seems that because the month and hour are not padded with zeros, none of the formating tricks will work, becuase if I try

```
test_string <- "06/20/2016 07:45"
strptime(test_string,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2016-06-20 07:45:00 EDT"
```

It works, but I dont think going through every row in the column and padding each date is a great option. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

josh

Comment: What is your locale? For me this works perfectly:

    > test_string <- "6/20/2016 07:45"  
    > test_string  
    [1] "6/20/2016 07:45"  
    > strptime(test_string, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")  
    [1] "2016-06-20 07:45:00 CEST"

Comment: The zero padding is not the problem. You could try `strptime("6/20/2016 7:45" ,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` and get the correct result without zero in front of the `6` or `7`. A different format is required for the two dates because of the different separators (dashes in one case, slashes in the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using lubridate , as follows :

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c("6/20/2016 7:45","2016-06-14 20:21:29.0")

> x
[1] "6/20/2016 7:45"        "2016-06-14 20:21:29.0"

> parse_date_time(x, orders = c("mdy hm", "ymd hms"))
[1] "2016-06-20 07:45:00 UTC" "2016-06-14 20:21:29 UTC"
>
```